# fetch last entity of database, increase it value and create new record PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have a job table, table has 10 records. now i want insert new jobs. solution is to find last entity of of job_id belongs to table. job id is 10.
i want find last entity then increase it with 1 then send that with content of textbox to table.

i have two page. first page ( admin_submit_job.php ) has textbox and fetching job_id:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="admin_send_job.php" >

<p>
  <label for="textfield">شغل جدید</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
  <label for="Submit"></label>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" />
</p>  

            <?php

   $db_host = 'localhost';
   $db_name= 'site';
   $db_table= 'job_list';
   $db_user = 'root';
   $db_pass = '';




$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'", $con);

$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");
$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT job_id FROM  $db_table
                   order by job_id desc
                   limit 1;",$con);
$id='job_id';

?>



</form>
```

and in second page ( admin_send_job.php ) i need get content of textbox and job_id.

```
   <?php


$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'job_list';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';


$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'", $con);

$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
 $ins = "INSERT INTO $db_table (job_id,job_name) VALUES ('" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']) . "','" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['textfield']) . "')";
$saved=mysql_query($ins );
mysql_close($con); 
echo "('" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']) . "')";

?>
```

i do not know what i should write for fetching and increase job_id. thanks...

Comment: is `job_id` auto_increment in db? if not, make it, and if so, you don't need to get and update that one.

Comment: can't you set your job_id to Autoincrement ? you do not need to insert it everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `auto_increment` `job_id`, you just need to do this

```
$ins = "INSERT INTO $db_table (job_name) VALUES ('" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['textfield']) . "')";
```

and it will insert new record with `job_id` 11 if the last one was 10